# Why does "nautilus --version" display "segmentation fault"?

Tags: nautilus, segmentation-fault

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and it runs quite fine. But when I issue the command `nautilus --version` in the terminal, I get this strange output:

```
GNOME nautilus 3.38.1
```

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

[image]

Why is this? I also have the nemo file manager installed in the system.
Thanks.

Comment: How did you get version 3.38.1 on 20.04? A [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nautilus&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) shows 20.04 should be on version 3.36.3

Comment: According to the version of `nautilus` and your pic you are using Ubuntu 20.10.  Even the version of `nautilus` in Ubuntu 20.04 gives the Segmentation Fault when checking the version from the command line.  Looks like the Segmentation Fault isn't causing any issues with `nautilus` and the way it operates.

Comment: I apologize for the error, I am using Ubuntu 20.10 :-p

Answer (score 2):

This is [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1820859) that will hopefully be resolved at some point in the near future. In the meantime, it’s probably best to not check the Nautilus version until after its next update